# emacs on gnome-terminal control keys

Tags: emacs, controls, key

I'm running emacs on a terminal mode (no window system) emacs -nw. I've few global keys defined in emacs like <kbd>C-;</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd> <kbd>C-/</kbd> <kbd>C-,</kbd> etc.. These control keys aren't taken for account in `-nw` mode. Any work around or solution please ?..

Comment: Terminals encode such key combinations through character sequences, but not all terminals have character sequences for keys such as `C-;`. I don't know if gnome-terminal can be configured; there are other terminals that can be, for example xterm. I suggest you ask on [Super User](http://superuser.com/), as this is a computer setup issue and not an emacs issue, and be prepared to be told to use a different terminal emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this problem myself. Basically, terminals are ASCII based, so key combos like <kbd>C-'</kbd> don't register. See [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/190351/control-punctuation-doesnt-register-in-terminal/190366#190366) answer on serverfault.