# Control-key combinations are not working when using emacs in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, agda

I'm trying to get started with [Agda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agda_(programming_language)). In order to do that I'm using (as recommended [here](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting-started/installation.html#os-x)) emacs within the terminal on my MacBook (macOS Monterey Version 12.0.1), which I've installed via homebrew.

**The problem**: Most of the key-combinations that include special characters like `C-,` or `C-=` are not working. The terminal makes a bell sound and no input is shown.

What I've tried so far:

- I've checked that those key-combinations are not used otherwise by the Terminal (via Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Keyboard) or my Mac (System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts)
- I tried to change some of the advanced options like "Declare terminal as: ", "Escape non-ASCII input with Control-V" and "Text encoding" (under Terminal > Preferences > Profiles > Advanced)

I've found [emacs on gnome-terminal control keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921385/emacs-on-gnome-terminal-control-keys), but I don't know what to do with the answers given there.

Comment: Have you tried Aquamacs? I've heard of people using that on OS X successfully.

Comment: This solution actually works. Thanks for the recommendation! Still wonder, though why those key-combinations didn't work in emacs...